# Is it possible to launch Bluetooth Discovery from a preference fragment xml

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I have a preference fragment and I'm trying to set up a custom preference option to do something. Initially I was looking for a way to add an itemclicklistener, but it would seem that with PreferenceFragments you can't do that.

```
 <Preference android:title="prefs_web_page" >
        <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
                android:data="http://www.example.com" />
 </Preference>
```

Using the above I would guess that something like this should work

```
   <Preference android:title="prefs_discover" >
   <intent android:action="android.intent.action.RUN"
         android:data ="BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE"/>
   </Preference>
```

I've tried it with RUN and View, neither seems to work. Is it even possible to do what I want?

If theres a more efficient alternative I'm open to suggestions.

EDIT: See discussion below.

I made an activity with some code to launch BT Discoverable, immediately after that code I use finish(); to close the activity so the user never sees it.

It's very dirty, but it gets the job done. Still open to suggestions on making it more efficient etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
mBTA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (mBTA == null){
        return;
    }
    if (!mBTA.isEnabled()){
        Intent enableBT = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBT, 0xDEADBEEF);
    }
    mBTA.startDiscovery();
```

But this is not a preference.

Comment: I should have clarified. I know how to do it within the class, like setting it to go on launch, which is what yours would do, or on a button click. but I need it as on on click within an options fragment. Its strange that there is no basic ability to do this. They have checkboxes,radio/select lists etc, but no basic perform actions

Comment: A thought occurs, maybe if I put that kind of code in an activity, then open the activity from the options menu. time to test it

Comment: sorry i don't know then :P